# PhoneGap and Galaxy s4 render issue

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy

I'm experiencing a weird issue on GS4 device when using PhoneGap, where by some of my elements of my web app are not displaying properly when the page renders, yet once that page is clicked or pressed, the elements layout properly. 
 A flickering white window accrued occasionally before translate events in my application.

The problem only accrued on GS4 and never accrued when I try it on other phones like GS4, Note or IPhone.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Some links that I found useful but still no solution. https://github.com/jaunesarmiento/fries/issues/31 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/NS4-SezuxH8

Answer (score 5):

Are those elements dynamically generated?
I too had the same issue, I figured out, it actually need some hardware acceleration(GPU acceleration). We should enable 3d rendering by css. 
Just use

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

for the particular element.
This worked for me, try it, may work for you.

pls check this [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Answer (score 2):

the problem in short: android. Depending on which version the GS4 is running on , the web-browser acts different and incurs different issues. IE i made a phonegap app which worked fine and then DOES NOT WORK AT ALL in jellybean. needless to say I dev native now. However, use translate and 3d transforms in your elements which causes all of the elements to be redrawn with hardware acceleration and forces a redraw of the elements if they are dynamically injected in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

try to manipulate with other elements, like:

```
$('#footer').fadeTo(1,0.99,function(){
   $('#footer').fadeTo(1,1);
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to force a redraw there are better ways of doing it. Like querying an elements width. Though that wont solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issue with a galaxy trend (android 4.0.4) : some changes in the page did not show correctly (redrawing some elements, hiding/showing others) untill I tap the screen, whereas it works perfectly on any other devices I've tested (from android 2.3 to 4.4).

I've tested many patches found in stack overflow and other places : add transcate3d in css, query elements width... nothing had effect;

It's only when I added `$myPage.find("[data-role=footer]").hide(0).show(0);` that my page finally rendered correctly on the galaxy trend.

In my case I think it works because it forces the redraw of the footer and the elements I'm hiding/showing are located in the footer.

Maybe forcing hide/show on other element could help in your case?